# Canonical Correlation in R with different matrix dimensions

Tags: r, correlation

I'm having difficulties about doing a CC analysis in R.
The assignment which I'm doing is from "Applied Multivariate Analysis" by Sharma, exercise 13.7, if you're familiar with it.

Basically, I'm asked to conduct a CCA on a set of variables. There are seven X variables, but only five Y variables, thus R complains that the dimensions are not compatible. See the image below for a visual representation of the data called *CETNEW*.

Edited (Changed from image to dput):

```
structure(list(...  
1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5"),
2 = c(2.72, 1.2, 0.82, 0.92, 1.19, 1, 1.45, 0.68, 0.98, 0.57, 1.07, 0.91), ...
3 = c(1.2, 3.78, 0.7, 1.04, 1.06, 1.32, 1.31, 0.56, 1, 0.79, 1.13, 1.38), ...    
4 = c(0.82, 0.7, 1.7, 0.59, 0.83, 1.08, 1.01, 0.65, 0.78, 0.66, 0.93, 0.77), ...  
5 = c(0.92, 1.04, 0.59, 3.09, 1.06, 0.93, 1.47, 0.62, 1.26, 0.51, 0.94, 0.85), ...  
6 = c(1.19, 1.06, 0.83, 1.06, 2.94, 1.36, 1.66, 0.68, 1.16, 0.77, 1.37, 1.11), ...  
7 = c(1, 1.32, 1.08, 0.93, 1.36, 2.94, 1.56, 0.9, 1.23, 0.78, 1.65, 1.31), ...  
8 = c(1.45, 1.31, 1.01, 1.47, 1.66, 1.56, 3.11, 1.03, 1.7, 0.81, 1.63, 1.44), ...  
9 = c(0.68, 0.56, 0.65, 0.62, 0.68, 0.9, 1.03, 1.71, 0.99, 0.65, 0.86, 0.72), ...  
10 = c(0.98, 1, 0.78, 1.26, 1.16, 1.23, 1.7, 0.99, 3.07, 0.61, 1.43, 1.28), ...  
11 = c(0.57, 0.79, 0.66, 0.51, 0.77, 0.78, 0.81, 0.65, 0.61, 2.83, 1.04, 0.84), ...  
12 = c(1.07, 1.13, 0.93, 0.94, 1.37, 1.65, 1.63, 0.86, 1.43, 1.04, 2.83, 1.6), ...  
13 = c(0.91, 1.38, 0.77, 0.85, 1.11, 1.31, 1.44, 0.72, 1.28, 0.84, 1.6, 4.01)),   
row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**What I've Done so Far**

```
CETNEW <- CETNEW[,-1] #To remove the non-numeric values
```

Create two variables (criterion and predictor variables) as:

```
CETNEWx <- CETNEW[1:7,]
CETNEWy <- CETNEW[8:12,]
```

Then I've been using various packages such as CCA, CCP and candisk. From CCA:

```
ccCETNEW <- cc(CETNEWx,CETNEWy)
```

Yields the following error message:

```
Error in cov(X, Y, use = "pairwise") : incompatible dimensions
```

The matcor function also from CCA, yields the following error message:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 5
```

Thus, it would seem that it all boils down to the different dimension problem. I've talked to my professor about it, but since he is using SAS, which apparently are compatible with this problem and could solve it, he could not help me.

Please, if you're familiar with canonical correlation and have had a similar problem before, any help regarding this topic is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use dput(CETNEW) and paste the result into your question as a code block. A picture is not useful. Are you sure you do not mean to be extracting two blocks of columns instead of two blocks of rows?

Comment: Alright, I changed it to dput. Not too familiar with the structure of the questions yet, but I'll get used to it thanks. Since I'm importing the data from and xls.file, I could transform the variables to be columns instead of rows, but I think the same problem would occur?

Comment: Something when wrong with `dput()` since you seem to be using a tibble, but I was able to salvage the data in the answer. A tibble should be observations = rows and columns = measurements/attributes of an observation, but yours seems to be transposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your data, notice the first column is divided into X and Y labels. That suggests to me that your data are transposed. If so, each column is an observation and the X and Y labels indicate various measurements taken on each observation. Canonical correlations are performed on two groups of measurements/variables from a single set of observations. First, here is the transposed data:

```
CETNEW.T <- structure(list(X1 = c(2.72, 1.2, 0.82, 0.92, 1.19, 1, 1.45, 0.68, 
0.98, 0.57, 1.07, 0.91), X2 = c(1.2, 3.78, 0.7, 1.04, 1.06, 1.32, 
1.31, 0.56, 1, 0.79, 1.13, 1.38), X3 = c(0.82, 0.7, 1.7, 0.59, 
0.83, 1.08, 1.01, 0.65, 0.78, 0.66, 0.93, 0.77), X4 = c(0.92, 
1.04, 0.59, 3.09, 1.06, 0.93, 1.47, 0.62, 1.26, 0.51, 0.94, 0.85
), X5 = c(1.19, 1.06, 0.83, 1.06, 2.94, 1.36, 1.66, 0.68, 1.16, 
0.77, 1.37, 1.11), X6 = c(1, 1.32, 1.08, 0.93, 1.36, 2.94, 1.56, 
0.9, 1.23, 0.78, 1.65, 1.31), X7 = c(1.45, 1.31, 1.01, 1.47, 
1.66, 1.56, 3.11, 1.03, 1.7, 0.81, 1.63, 1.44), Y1 = c(0.68, 
0.56, 0.65, 0.62, 0.68, 0.9, 1.03, 1.71, 0.99, 0.65, 0.86, 0.72
), Y2 = c(0.98, 1, 0.78, 1.26, 1.16, 1.23, 1.7, 0.99, 3.07, 0.61, 
1.43, 1.28), Y3 = c(0.57, 0.79, 0.66, 0.51, 0.77, 0.78, 0.81, 
0.65, 0.61, 2.83, 1.04, 0.84), Y4 = c(1.07, 1.13, 0.93, 0.94, 
1.37, 1.65, 1.63, 0.86, 1.43, 1.04, 2.83, 1.6), Y5 = c(0.91, 
1.38, 0.77, 0.85, 1.11, 1.31, 1.44, 0.72, 1.28, 0.84, 1.6, 4.01
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Now the analysis runs fine:

```
library("CCA")
str(CETNEW.T)
# 'data.frame': 12 obs. of  12 variables:
#  $ X1: num  2.72 1.2 0.82 0.92 1.19 1 1.45 0.68 0.98 0.57 ...
#  $ X2: num  1.2 3.78 0.7 1.04 1.06 1.32 1.31 0.56 1 0.79 ...
#  $ X3: num  0.82 0.7 1.7 0.59 0.83 1.08 1.01 0.65 0.78 0.66 ...
#  $ X4: num  0.92 1.04 0.59 3.09 1.06 0.93 1.47 0.62 1.26 0.51 ...
#  $ X5: num  1.19 1.06 0.83 1.06 2.94 1.36 1.66 0.68 1.16 0.77 ...
#  $ X6: num  1 1.32 1.08 0.93 1.36 2.94 1.56 0.9 1.23 0.78 ...
#  $ X7: num  1.45 1.31 1.01 1.47 1.66 1.56 3.11 1.03 1.7 0.81 ...
#  $ Y1: num  0.68 0.56 0.65 0.62 0.68 0.9 1.03 1.71 0.99 0.65 ...
#  $ Y2: num  0.98 1 0.78 1.26 1.16 1.23 1.7 0.99 3.07 0.61 ...
#  $ Y3: num  0.57 0.79 0.66 0.51 0.77 0.78 0.81 0.65 0.61 2.83 ...
#  $ Y4: num  1.07 1.13 0.93 0.94 1.37 1.65 1.63 0.86 1.43 1.04 ...
#  $ Y5: num  0.91 1.38 0.77 0.85 1.11 1.31 1.44 0.72 1.28 0.84 ...
X <- CETNEW.T[, 1:7]
Y <- CETNEW.T[, 8:12]
ccCETNEW <- cc(X, Y)
```

`ccCETNEW` is list with 5 parts containing the results.